# Собеседование по Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Здравствуйте, вот недавно начала изучать Ruby on Rails и возник такой вопрос:

Как происходит набор на место Junior-ов ( и вобще есть ли в них спрос, я имею ввиду на Украине ). Хотелось бы попробовать свои силы в Rails-разработке только вот не знаю с чего начать и к чему готовиться на собеседовании. Уже много читал, что везде нужен опыт работы - но как его получить. Какие вопросы ждать на собеседовании, если возьмут - можно будет рассчитывать на помощь - просто хотелось бы с начала научиться и набраться опыта ( готов даже работать за еду - но что бы учили )

И если есть люди, которые сами недавно проходили что-то подобное опишите как это происходит

Comment: Один фреймворк слишком узкая специализация. Хороший программист может перейти на другую платформу разок почитав документацию. В таком случае шансы найти работу увеличиваются на порядок.

Comment: > начала изучать
> много читал

с полом определяйтесь =)

Comment: Тоже заметил

Comment: "готов даже работать за еду - но что бы учили" - никто вас учить не будет, максимум могут подсказывать и пинать в нужном направлении, посему, как не прискорбно, учиться надо будет самой(ому)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Напиши свой блог, может быть форум. Доведи результат до идеала. Этого опыта вполне хватит чтобы устроиться junior'ом.

Answer (score 5):

В моем понимании Junior это чернорабочий. Главное чтобы он понимал синтаксис языка, владел основными приемами, немного умел общаться с VCS, заваривать кофе, поддерживать разговор в курилке на темы о футболе, женщинах и машинах :)

Ну если серьезно, то я как наниматель всегда хотел видеть от Junior'а (в порядке убывания приоритета):

1. Способность и желание пахать с утра до вечера
2. Хорошее знание самого языка и инструментов разработки
3. Понимание основных паттернов

Меня никогда не интересовали потуги джуниора в архитектуре, дизайне и проч. - это всегда выглядит смешно и глупо.

Answer (score 1):

Как получить опыт? очень просто. Берете задачу (можно найти на сайтах фрилансеров идею). Делаете, выкладываете на [github.com](http://github.com). Параллельно на нем же ищете различные проекты, скачиваете себе, смотрите, изучаете, исправляете ошибки, делаете pull-request. За пол года можно создать себе хорошее портфолио и опыта получить. Рассылая резюме - добавляете ссылку на свой профиль.

Answer (score 0):

Я приходил в компанию на место Ruby On Rails developer'а даже ни разу не попробовав ruby. Дня 2-3 потыкался - создал небольшой проектик и попросил нормальную задачку. Так и повелось))) Хочу сказать, что как только вы более ли менее поймете что есть Rails сразу захочется понять что есть Ruby... Извините, возможно за оффтоп, но каких-либо критериев нет - все зависит от того, какая компания и какой вы разработчик.